# Does the destructor get called when a C++ temporary object is destroyed? Why does this code only output three "deconstruction" messages?

Tags: c++, destructor

```cpp
class demo{
    private:
    int x;
    public:
    demo(int t):x(t) {cout<<"constructor"<<endl;}
    demo(const demo& t):x(t.x) {cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;}
    demo& operator=(const int& t){
        x=t;
        cout<<"assignment"<<endl;
    }
    demo& operator=(const demo& t){
        x=t.x;
        cout<<"copy assignment"<<endl;
    }
    ~demo()
    {
        cout<<"deconstruction"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    demo x=2; // if the deconstruct function is called here, then it should be three "deconstruction"
    demo y(2);
    y=3;
}
```

the code above output two "deconstruction", I suppose it should be three.
because "demo x = 2", in my opinion is just like "demo x = demo(2)", so when demo(2) is deconstructed, it should be a "deconstruction" message ouputed.
then at the end of the program, x and y is deconstructed.
so there should be 3 "deconstruction" output.

Comment: your class invokes undefined behaviour, because your assignment operators never return a value

Comment: Do the construction and destruction messages match up?  C++ has a rule called "copy elision" that sometimes eliminates a temporary object (removing a pair of copy construction and destruction)

Comment: @Raildex: `demo x=2;` is "copy-initialization", which has semantics of creating an temporary, then copying it to the final object.  But elision is allowed to eliminate the extra object.

Comment: I reviewed your demo a bit to illustrate what happens when: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a30d07fadabddaf5)

Comment: @BenVoigt `demo x = 2` is equivalent to `demo x = demo(2)`. In this case, `demo(2)` is a prvalue expression of the same class type (`demo`), so copy elision is mandatory since C++17. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: @BenVoigt `y=3;` is UB

Comment: @VLL Note that the term _copy elision_ is misleading (though heavily used) in this case since C++17. I think the more precise term is _deferred temporary materialization_. There is an important difference in that for CE, there needs to be a copy/move constructor to be elided. This is not required with DTM (such that it works even with instances of `std::atomic`, where CE does not work).